# How to iterabily enter a list of strings into a search box with selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Assume that I have a list of terms:

```
a_lis = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish', 'worm', ..., 'ferret']
```

Also, I have a website which have a search box:

[image]

How can I pass and search each element of `a_lis` into the search box?. After looking at the [docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html) I tried this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Firefox()


for e in a_lis:
    driver.get("https:www.example.com")
    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("searchbox")
    inputElement.send_keys(e)
    inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.back()
```

However, it is not working. Since it just pass all the string elements of `a_lis` one by one without doing any search. Thus, how can I pass each element one by one and then search it into the search box?. In other words my main objective is to search for each string in a_lis individually into the search box.

**UPDATE**

I tried to do inside the for loop:

```
driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

Nonetheless, it did not worked.

Comment: Do you mean you want it to search for each string in `a_lis` individually?

Comment: Just put `driver.get("https:www.example.com")` at the start of the loop.

Comment: So is it entering one string and hitting enter correctly? and by that I mean, does the enter key hit the search button and do whatever it is supposed to do?

Comment: No it is entering all the strings at once, which is wrong. Also it is not returning in order to search for the next term in the list @JayeshDoolani

Comment: @AlexHall, that worked out. However it is not doing enter over the search button.. How can I search for a term and then return?.

Comment: ah, I see. So the enter key is not pressing the search button and hence it's continuing the loop and entering the next string to type. Instead of sending the `Keys.ENTER`, click on search button manually

Comment: How do I do that @JayeshDoolani?.. I am pretty new with selenium

Comment: @tumbleweed check my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140008/discussion-between-jayesh-doolani-and-tumbleweed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made this example for you to reference.  I go to stack overflow, search each tag synchronously and then close the driver.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/")
for query in ["java","python"]:
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name("input").send_keys(query)
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name("input").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    # alternatively, find the search button element and click it.
    # additional functionality here
    sleep(5)
    print "Query link: ",driver.current_url
    driver.back()
sleep(1)
driver.quit()
```

- important things to note, with every iteration you need to return to the search page `driver.back()` and find the search bar element again `driver.find_element` to avoid a stale element reference error.

Comment: Double check that the id for the search bar is searchbox

Comment: How can I get the current query link?. I tried using `current_url` after `driver.back()`. However, it is not printing the current query link.

Comment: increment sleep time, or wait for page to finish loading: `sleep(n) n, is some number such that after n seconds page loaded` then print the url `print "Query link: ",driver.current_url`.

Answer (score 1):

The line `inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` is not hitting the search button, hence it continues in the loop and enters the next string in the list.

Instead of sending the enter key, try clicking manually on the search button, like
`driver.find_element_by_id("ID OF SEARCH BUTTON GOES HERE").click()`

Then, when you are done with this input, use `driver.back()` in last line of your loop to go back to previous page, which will bring you to page with the search input.

So your code will look like this:

```
driver.get("https:www.example.com")
for e in a_lis:
    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("searchbox")
    inputElement.clear()
    inputElement.send_keys(e)
    driver.find_element_by_id("ID OF SEARCH BUTTON GOES HERE").click()
    # do something here for the new page
    driver.back() #takes you back to search another string
```

Comment: Thanks but I got: `NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="searchbox"]
`

Comment: well, you have to make sure that the id of search box is correct. This error suggests there is no element on webpage with id="searchbox". If the searchbox does not have a unique id, use xPath

Comment: Just a heads up you are using javascript comments in your code, but good answer.

Comment: I do that all time